# Find duplicate contacts from AddressBook

Tags: ios, swift2

I have made an app that import contact from AddressBook using ABAddressBook framework. Now I want add a function that detect Duplicate contact and merge them.
But I have problem with my "Matching  algorithm"
It's cost so much time. Example I have 100 contacts so the for loop must go 99*99*98..... time

```
for index in 0 ..< contacts.count - 1 {
    let nextIndx = index + 1
    for otherIndx in  nextIndx ..< people.count {

    }
}
```

Could anyone show me how to improve this one or any other way?

Comment: AddressBook has been deprecated. You should be using the Contacts framework. For more information on that: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015328

Comment: But I'm working with this and I need help on algorithm. Can you help me?

Comment: Hmm. Have you tried creating an array with each contact, then finding if one of them is related to all the rest?

Comment: I have done it. But the matter is I think the algorithm is cost so much time. Do you have any suggestion?